# Is there a way to prevent VB from using character alt codes?

Tags: .net, vb.net, ascii

I've been messing  around with ASCII in Visual Basic (on .NET) for a school project, and recently discovered something that I don't know how to get around. Converting an integer to ASCII using `Asc()` and then copying it to another script and converting to an integer using `Chr()` will return the wrong characters in some cases. For example.

```
Dim i As String = Chr(29) 
Console.WriteLine(i)         ' Returns ↔

Dim i2 As Integer = Asc("↔") 
Console.WriteLine(i2)        ' Returns 63
```

Currently, I think this could be due to a couple things:

- Some ASCII codes cannot be displayed (29 is GS, which I don't believe can be shown) and so reverts to using 29's alt code which is ↔.
- The `Asc()` function may resort to other character encoding forms where ↔ is 63?
- I have not used correct methods for doing this task - very possible.

Could someone explain to me why this occurs and/or show me a way of preventing this problem from happening? This seems like a pretty annoying issue for people who use VB and character encoding if it is a genuine problem, however I would be surprised by this as I haven't been using character encoding for long and have probably missed something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that `Chr` returns a `Char`, why are you assigning it to a `String` variable? You really ought to turn `Option Strict On` and be more careful with your data types.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here? If you assign the result of `Chr` to a `Char` variable and then feed that to `Asc`, you'll get the same number you started with. Just because two characters look the same in the UI doesn't mean they are the same. The code you posted doesn't do what you describe.

Comment: FYI @jmcilhinney the difference that is noted is with the character that is produced by holding down the `alt` key and then typing 29 on the numeric keypad.  In theory, this should produce ASCII 29, so it's a little surprising that the result of `Asc` on it is 63.

Comment: At a guess, this is an IDE thing where the IDE text editor is changing the character that you type.  Disassembly shows that the editor is turning it into U+2194 Left Right Arrow.

Comment: 63 is the character code for '?'.  In other words, there is no conversion.  Asc() and Chr() use the legacy conversions that were used in MS-Dos and Windows 9x.  Based on code pages (aka "ansi"), there were only 256 defined codes.  Unicode rules the world today, you need to use AscW() and ChrW().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a little investigation, it seems like this is the result of a perhaps surprising interaction of the behavior of the IDE text editor with the `Asc` function.  As another answer noted, the text editor supports the full Unicode character set (including in identifiers e.g. `ಠ_ಠ` is a legal identifier in .NET).  When I used a character version of the `Asc` test (i.e. `Asc("↔"c)`) and checked on the disassembly, I found that it was processed as 0x2194, i.e. Unicode code point U+2194 Left Right Arrow.

This suggests that the IDE text editor is making a conversion of the ASCII into the best equivalent Unicode code point.  Calling `Asc` on the result is returning 63 which corresponds to a question mark, which I believe is the correct result for trying to represent a Unicode code point when there isn't a valid conversion for it.  The correctness of this behavior is debatable, but I'm not sure we should expect too much of `Asc` as I would view it as more of a compatibility routine anyway---it appears that it isn't designed to try to back-convert a Unicode code point that lies beyond U+FF (or possibly U+7F) and will instead just treat it as `?`.

Note that if I call `AscW` instead of `Asc`, I get 8596 (or &H2194) which is what I would expect based on the previous investigation of the disassembly.

As a practical matter, this doesn't seem like it should be a problem.  If you really care about the exact character code, then you should use `Chr` or `ChrW` to generate the character instead of relying on the IDE rendering your typed character exactly.

Comment: *"Calling Asc on the result is returning 63"*. No it isn't, as my answer deomstrates. You're not passing the result of `Chr` to `Asc`. You're passing a literal `String`. What you keep describing and what your code actually does are two different things. The problem here is your understanding. There's likely no good reason to be using `Asc` and `Chr` at all. You should be working with Unicode characters and using `Convert.ToInt32` and `Convert.ToChar`. We're not in VB6 any more Toto.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Uh, no, calling `Asc` on the result of directly entering the string (rather than calling `Chr`) is exactly what is returning 63.  That's the whole point of the question and my answer---trying to understand the mismatch between entering character 29 on the keyboard and assigning it using `Chr(29)`.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Craig is right. The issue is not passing back the result of `Chr` to `Asc`, but rather the literal `String`. Passing the `String` results in this issue, passing `Chr` to `Asc` as you described is not a possibility here.

Answer (score 0):

The "↔" you typed at the line

```
Dim i2 As Integer = Asc("↔")
```

is not the same as the result of

```
Dim i As String = Chr(29)
```

Because your source code is Unicode encoded, it's not ASCII

[image: Visual Studio screen]

Comment: Is there any way to switch to ASCII encoding?

Comment: It shouldn't matter that it ends up in Unicode.  It's still surprising that a character that is expected to be ASCII code 29 reports back as 63.

Comment: @henry See the routines in `Encoding`.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to convert back to your original value as ASCII cannot represents all the Unicode values. The best way to handle all characters is to work in unicode (or UTF8) in all "sides". That's a general advice, don't work with ASCII with texts, always unicode, or you'll have issues

Comment: Unfortunately I need to work with ASCII. My task was to create a Vernam Cipher using ASCII, and so any other approach would not fit within my guidelines for this project.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't converting the output that you get from `Chr` using `Asc` if you did then you'd get the expected result. This:

```vb
Dim i = 29
Dim ch = Chr(i)

Console.WriteLine(ch)

i = Asc(ch)

Console.WriteLine(i)
```

outputs this:

```
↔
29
```

What your code is doing is not what you describe.

Comment: Apologies, the explanation was confusing. My code however does show the issue. I want to be able to copy the output of `Chr(29)` (which is "↔") away from the program and paste it as an input into another program, where `Asc("↔")` will not give 29, but 63. @kipy mentioned this was something to do with Unicode encoding instead of ASCII, but I have no idea how to switch this to ASCII.

Comment: Are you familiar with the alt-keypad trick for entering characters?  Alt-xxx will enter the ASCII character by code, Alt-0xxx will enter the ANSI/OEM character by code.  The question is about what's happening when you key in the character using Alt-(keypad)29.

Comment: Here is a character list of OEM/ANSI/Unicode https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/character-table-oem-ansi-and-unicode.html *29 0x1D ␝ ↔ Control  Control Codes*